# (Space)ship identification

Tags: spaceship, toys, object-identification

I just bought this miniature from my local comic shop. It was near some toy *micro machines* of Star Wars but I failed to find the ship by browsing the *vehicles* section in the  [Star Wars.com](http://www.starwars.com/databank) databank.

So probably is from another Science Fiction franchise. Could somebody identify this spaceship, please?

[image: Model spaceship]

Comment: It appears to be a Limited Edition Galor Class. You can see one 'in-box' from [this](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91CS8lYDvcL._SL1500_.jpg) collector's set. Retail value without the display stand, probably about $5. You can see a better image [here](http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5026/5601379417_a9b86a4752_z.jpg) (middle-bottom)

Comment: I used to have this exact miniature when I was growing up. Suddenly, I miss them :(

Comment: please edit the image. should be less than 100k in size. this single image could cost someone's phone data plan...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That's a Galor Cardassian spaceship from TNG and DS9

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Galor_class

(the images from Memory Alpha are sadly terrible - here are better examples)
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 16):

That is a [Galor-class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Galor_class) [Cardassian](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cardassian_military) warship from Star Trek: The Next Generation and Deep Space 9.

[image]